# Heroku deployment failure - missing package xi.pc

Tags: node.js, git, npm, heroku, heroku-cli

I am trying to deploy a node.js app through Heroku and I repeatedly get an error stating that

> Package xi was not found in the pkg-config search path.

I have tried locating it in my drive and getting around it by changing the build command (I am not sure if I actually did this correctly).

Could someone tell me how to add it to `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` or otherwise resolve my issue?

Not sure if this applied but I am running on Windows 10

Here is the run log:

```
Counting objects: 100% (6988/6988), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (2066/2066), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6988/6988), 84.15 MiB | 588.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 6988 (delta 4930), reused 6674 (delta 4712), pack-reused 0
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Using buildpack: heroku/nodejs
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote:
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        USE_NPM_INSTALL=true
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote:
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  16.6.1
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   7.19.1
remote:
remote:        Resolving node version 16.6.1...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 16.6.1...
remote:        Bootstrapping npm 7.19.1 (replacing 7.20.3)...
remote:        npm 7.19.1 installed
remote:
remote: -----> Installing dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules (package.json + package-lock)
remote:        npm ERR! code 1
remote:        npm ERR! path /tmp/build_1c155a17/node_modules/gl
remote:        npm ERR! command failed
remote:        npm ERR! command sh -c prebuild-install || node-gyp rebuild
remote:        npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
remote:        npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@7.1.2
remote:        npm ERR! gyp info using node@16.6.1 | linux | x64
remote:        npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.8.10 found at "/usr/bin/python3"
remote:        npm ERR! gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v16.6.1/node-v16.6.1-headers.tar.gz
remote:        npm ERR! gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v16.6.1/node-v16.6.1-headers.tar.gz
remote:        npm ERR! gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v16.6.1/SHASUMS256.txt
remote:        npm ERR! gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v16.6.1/SHASUMS256.txt
remote:        npm ERR! (node:975) [DEP0150] DeprecationWarning: Setting process.config is deprecated. In the future the property will be read-only.
remote:        npm ERR! (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
remote:        npm ERR! gyp info spawn /usr/bin/python3
remote:        npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
remote:        npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/tmp/build_1c155a17/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
remote:        npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
remote:        npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
remote:        npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
remote:        npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
remote:        npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/tmp/build_1c155a17/node_modules/gl/build/config.gypi',
remote:        npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
remote:        npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/tmp/build_1c155a17/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
remote:        npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
remote:        npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/app/.cache/node-gyp/16.6.1/include/node/common.gypi',
remote:        npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
remote:        npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
remote:        npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/app/.cache/node-gyp/16.6.1',
remote:        npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/tmp/build_1c155a17/node_modules/node-gyp',
remote:        npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/app/.cache/node-gyp/16.6.1/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
remote:        npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/tmp/build_1c155a17/node_modules/gl',
remote:        npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
remote:        npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
remote:        npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
remote:        npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
remote:        npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
remote:        npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
remote:        npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
remote:        npm ERR! Package xi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
remote:        npm ERR! Perhaps you should add the directory containing `xi.pc'
remote:        npm ERR! to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
remote:        npm ERR! No package 'xi' found
remote:        npm ERR! gyp: Call to 'pkg-config --libs-only-L --libs-only-other x11 xi xext' returned exit status 1 while in angle/src/angle.gyp. while loading dependencies of binding.gyp while trying to load binding.gyp
remote:        npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
remote:        npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
remote:        npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/tmp/build_1c155a17/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:351:16)
remote:        npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:394:28)
remote:        npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)
remote:        npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-1101-aws
remote:        npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/tmp/build_1c155a17/node_modules/node/bin/node" "/tmp/build_1c155a17/node_modules/.bin/node-gyp" "rebuild"
remote:        npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /tmp/build_1c155a17/node_modules/gl
remote:        npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v16.6.1
remote:        npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v7.1.2
remote:        npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
remote:
remote:        npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote:        npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.oi8QP/_logs/2022-04-12T04_27_10_425Z-debug.log
remote:
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:
remote:        If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
remote:        https://help.heroku.com/
remote:
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote:  !
remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built: 1181ec50ab370b81edb24bd2bc64c3a466666aac
remote:  !
remote:  ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version 1181ec50ab370b81edb24bd2bc64c3a466666aac
remote:  ! at least twice. One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code from a different branch.
remote:  !
remote:  ! If you are developing on a branch and deploying via git you must run:
remote:  !
remote:  !     git push heroku <branchname>:main
remote:  !
remote:  ! This article goes into details on the behavior:
remote:  !   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to mighty-ridge-11868.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/mighty-ridge-11868.git
 ! [remote rejected] main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/mighty-ridge-11868.git'
```

Answer (score 3):

It is failing during the installation of the gl npm package:

```
npm ERR! path /tmp/build_1c155a17/node_modules/gl
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gl
The gl npm package has the following system dependencies:

> - Python 2.7
> - A GNU C++ environment (available via the build-essential package on apt)
> - libxi-dev
> - Working and up to date OpenGL drivers
> - GLEW
> - pkg-config

Playing around with `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` won't help if you don't have it installed.

```
remote:        npm ERR! Package xi was not found in the pkg-config search path.
remote:        npm ERR! Perhaps you should add the directory containing `xi.pc'
remote:        npm ERR! to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
remote:        npm ERR! No package 'xi' found
remote:        npm ERR! gyp: Call to 'pkg-config --libs-only-L --libs-only-other x11 xi xext' returned exit status 1 while in angle/src/angle.gyp. while loading dependencies of binding.gyp while trying to load binding.gyp
remote:        npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error
```

You need to install the following apt packages first before installing your npm dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential libxi-dev libglu1-mesa-dev libglew-dev pkg-config
```

Heroku has an Apt buildpack: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-apt

```
heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 heroku-community/apt
```

You will need an `Aptfile` with the content

```
build-essential libxi-dev libglu1-mesa-dev libglew-dev pkg-config
```

How to use multiple buildpacks? (You need node and Apt.)
See: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app